# MYSQL select name from id

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to get the name from the author id in table post.

I have these 2 tables:

post:

| id | authorID | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Header title Example |

and users:

| id | author | [..] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dennis | ... |
| 2 | Alexa | ... |
| 3 | Roger | ... |

My SQL:

```
SELECT author
FROM users
WHERE authorID = users.id
```

any suggestions?

the solution is:

```
SELECT id, (SELECT author FROM users WHERE id = p.authorID) 
FROM users
WHERE authorID = users.id
```

Comment: At this point, 5 minutes in the company of any basic, introductory book or tutorial would be useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.author AS author_name
FROM users u
INNER JOIN post p
ON u.id = p.authorID;
```

Answer (score 3):

You want a basic join here:

```sql
SELECT p.id, COALESCE(u.author, 'NA') AS author
FROM post p
LEFT JOIN users u
    ON u.id = p.authorID
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest to what you wrote without using join.
`Select users.* From post, users Where post.authorID = users.id`